# Access VBA - who has sendas permissions

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I have several users that will be sending emails out from an automated mail merge.  However, some of the emails need to be sent out from a group email account.  I found the `SentOnBehalfOfName` property and intend to assign this group email to it, but to cover my bases I need to make sure that their Exchange account has that capability.  (some do, and some don't).  Is there a way to check for this.  I'm guessing it's something like

```
If olMailItem.SendAs = true then
   olMailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "xyz@abc.com"
end if
```

Comment: I've revised my method.  I just created a tag in my user table to tag users that I know have the SendAs option set up in Exchange.  I use the IF statement to look for this tag and then add the `.SentOnBehalfOfName` only for those users.    Ideally, there would be some way to just check for the "SendAs" capability in Outlook.  In my tests, if they don't have the SendAs option, then users name and the sent on behalf of name appear in the FROM field, and the email gets bounced as if the recipient(???)  is not recognized.